# How to change the text of a div with the text of another div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I have 5 divs and when one is clicked is selected and after you click on another div the numbers needs to be switched between them(for example I click on the first one with 7 and after that I click on the third one with 15, now the first div needs to have the number 15 and the third one to have the number 7 and so on).

```
    <div class='cards'>
        <div class='box'>7</div>
        <div class='box'>6</div>
        <div class='box'>15</div>
        <div class='box'>8</div>
        <div class='box'>3</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to keep a global for holding a reference to the selected `div`, then adding a `click event` to all div's with `className` `box`, on the click event check to see if the global is `null`, if not switch it's value with the previously selected `div`, else store a reference to the selected `div`

```js
let switchBox = null;

const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

for(let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
   boxes[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
       SwitchValues(this);
   });
}

function SwitchValues(box){
   if(switchBox === null){
      switchBox = box;
   }else{
      const switchText = switchBox.textContent;
      const boxText = box.textContent;
      box.textContent = switchText;
      switchBox.textContent = boxText;
      switchBox = null;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class='cards'>
        <div class='box'>7</div>
        <div class='box'>6</div>
        <div class='box'>15</div>
        <div class='box'>8</div>
        <div class='box'>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store click counts in a variable.

1. On the click of div with 7, push 7 into an array
2. On the click of div 15, push 15 into array too
3. Now replace the values
4. Clear array on the even values of the click counter.